# list of data frames, trying to create new column with normalisation values for each dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, normalization

I'm new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and mostly work with [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s. A frequent task is to [normalize](/questions/tagged/normalize) counts for several parameters from several data frames. I have a demo dataset:
**dataset**

| Season | Product | Quality | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Winter | Apple | bad | 345 |
| Winter | Apple | good | 13 |
| Winter | Potato | bad | 23 |
| Winter | Potato | good | 66 |
| Winter | Beer | bad | 345 |
| Winter | Beer | good | 34 |
| Summer | Apple | bad | 88 |
| Summer | Apple | good | 90 |
| Summer | Potato | bad | 123 |
| Summer | Potato | good | 457 |
| Summer | Beer | bad | 44 |
| Summer | Beer | good | 546 |

What I want to do is **add a column "FC" ([tag:fold change]) for "Sales". FC must be calculated for each "Season" and "Product" according to "Quality".** "Bad" is the baseline.

Desired result:

| Season | Product | Quality | Sales | FC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Winter | Apple | bad | 345 | 1.00 |
| Winter | Apple | good | 13 | 0.04 |
| Winter | Potato | bad | 23 | 1.00 |
| Winter | Potato | good | 66 | 2.87 |
| Winter | Beer | bad | 345 | 1.00 |
| Winter | Beer | good | 34 | 0.10 |
| Summer | Apple | bad | 88 | 1.00 |
| Summer | Apple | good | 90 | 1.02 |
| Summer | Potato | bad | 123 | 1.00 |
| Summer | Potato | good | 457 | 3.72 |
| Summer | Beer | bad | 44 | 1.00 |
| Summer | Beer | good | 546 | 12.41 |

One way to do it is to [filter](/questions/tagged/filter) first by "Season" and then by "Product" (e.g. creating subset data frame *subset_winter_apple*) and then calculate FC similarly to this:

```
subset_winter_apple$FC = subset_winter_apple$Sales / subset_winter_apple$Sales[1]
```

Later on, I can then combine all subset dataframes again e.g. using `rbind()` to reconstitute the original data frame with the FC column. However, this is highly inefficient. So I thought of [split](/questions/tagged/split)ting the data frame and creating a [list](/questions/tagged/list):

```
split(
  dataset, 
  list(dataset$Season, dataset$Product)
)
```

However, now I struggle with the normalisation (FC calculation) as I do not know how to *reference the specific first cell value* of "Sales" in the *list of data frames* so that each value in that column in each listed data frame is individually normalized. I did manage to calculate an FC value for the list, however, it is an exact copy in each listed data frame from the first one using [lappy](/questions/tagged/lappy):

```
lapply(
  dataset, 
  function(DF){DF$FC = dataset[[1]]$Sales/dataset[[1]]$Sales[1]; DF}
)
```

Clearly, I do not know **how to reference the first cell in a specific column to normalize the entire column for each listed data frame**. Can somebody please help me?

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Please post your data using `dput` (e.g., `dput(yourdata)`), so we can use them and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### dplyr solution

Using logical indexing within a grouped `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(Season, Product) %>%
  mutate(FC = Sales / Sales[Quality == "bad"]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   Season Product Quality Sales      FC
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
 1 Winter Apple   bad       345  1     
 2 Winter Apple   good       13  0.0377
 3 Winter Potato  bad        23  1     
 4 Winter Potato  good       66  2.87  
 5 Winter Beer    bad       345  1     
 6 Winter Beer    good       34  0.0986
 7 Summer Apple   bad        88  1     
 8 Summer Apple   good       90  1.02  
 9 Summer Potato  bad       123  1     
10 Summer Potato  good      457  3.72  
11 Summer Beer    bad        44  1     
12 Summer Beer    good      546 12.4
```

#### Base R solution

Using `by()`:

```
dataset <- by(
  dataset,
  list(dataset$Season, dataset$Product),
  \(x) transform(x, FC = Sales / Sales[Quality == "bad"])
)

dataset <- do.call(rbind, dataset)

dataset[order(as.numeric(rownames(dataset))), ]
```

```
   Season Product Quality Sales          FC
1  Winter   Apple     bad   345  1.00000000
2  Winter   Apple    good    13  0.03768116
3  Winter  Potato     bad    23  1.00000000
4  Winter  Potato    good    66  2.86956522
5  Winter    Beer     bad   345  1.00000000
6  Winter    Beer    good    34  0.09855072
7  Summer   Apple     bad    88  1.00000000
8  Summer   Apple    good    90  1.02272727
9  Summer  Potato     bad   123  1.00000000
10 Summer  Potato    good   457  3.71544715
11 Summer    Beer     bad    44  1.00000000
12 Summer    Beer    good   546 12.40909091
```